# How to get a period of time with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

If a `np.datetime64` type data is given, how to get a period of time around the time?

For example, if `np.datetime64('2020-04-01T21:32')` is given to a function, I want the function to return `np.datetime64('2020-04-01T21:30')` and `np.datetime64('2020-04-01T21:39')` - 10 minutes around the given time.

Is there any way to do this with numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy does not have a built in time period like Pandas does.

If all you want are two time stamps the following function should work.

```py
def ten_minutes_around(t):
    t = ((t.astype('<M8[m]') # Truncate time to integer minute representation
         .astype('int')      # Convert to integer representation
         // 10) * 10         # Remove any sub 10 minute minutes
        ).astype('<M8[m]')   # convert back to minute timestamp
    return np.array([t, t + np.timedelta64(10, 'm')]).T
```

For example:

```
for t in [np.datetime64('2020-04-01T21:32'), np.datetime64('2052-02-03T13:56:03.172')]:
    s, e = ten_minutes_around(t)
    print(s, t, e)
```

gives:

```
2020-04-01T21:30 2020-04-01T21:32 2020-04-01T21:40
2652-02-03T13:50 2652-02-03T13:56:03.172 2652-02-03T14:00
```

and

```py
ten_minutes_around(np.array([
    np.datetime64('2020-04-01T21:32'),
    np.datetime64('2652-02-03T13:56:03.172'),
    np.datetime64('1970-04-01'),
]))
```

gives

```
array([['2020-04-01T21:30', '2020-04-01T21:40'],
       ['2652-02-03T13:50', '2652-02-03T14:00'],
       ['1970-04-01T00:00', '1970-04-01T00:10']], dtype='datetime64[m]')
```

Answer (score 1):

To do so we can get the **minute** from the given time and subtract it from the given time to get the starting of the period and add 9 minutes to get the ending time of the period.

```py
import numpy as np
time = '2020-04-01T21:32'
dt = np.datetime64(time) 
base = (dt.tolist().time().minute) % 10 // base would be 3 in this case

start = dt - np.timedelta64(base,'m')
end = start + np.timedelta64(9,'m')
print(start,end,sep='\n')
```

I hope this helps.